# Problems setting equal spacing between views in a UIBezierPath

Tags: swift

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let amountOfViews = 3
    let difference: CGFloat = 360 / CGFloat(amountOfViews)
    for i in 0...amountOfViews - 1{
        print((CGFloat(i) * difference))
        let view2 = UIView()
        view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view2.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view.addSubview(view2)
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.09, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.35, constant: 0).isActive = true
    let orbit = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: self.view.frame.origin, radius: CGFloat(self.view.frame.height * 0.3), startAngle:  CGFloat(i) * difference, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2 + CGFloat(i) * difference, clockwise: true)
    orbit.path = circlePath.cgPath
    orbit.duration = 10
    orbit.isAdditive = true
    orbit.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    orbit.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced
    orbit.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
    view2.layer.add(orbit, forKey: "orbit")
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

This is the print:

```
0.0
120.0
240.0
```

To me the difference between the views should be correct, however it is not. The views are touching eachother while they should have equal spacing between them. When setting the amountOfViews to 4, this is the result:

[image]

That looks weird as well. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of degrees vs radians The `UIBezierPath` requires angle values in radians. Your `i` variable is in degrees.

```
let radians = (CGFloat(i) * difference) / 180 * CGFloat.pi
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: self.view.frame.origin, radius: CGFloat(self.view.frame.height * 0.3), startAngle: radians, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2 + radians, clockwise: true)
```